# DataDog Jira Integration Configuration JSON

Tags: jira, datadog

We currently are using DataDog as our alert monitoring and Jira for ticket creation. Recently, we've been tasked to automatically create a Jira ticket when a DD monitor triggers an event. Currently, it's set up to just hit Slack but we want a ticket to be created under a Jira Epic when it's triggered. According to the Jira API, this is what we get returned for an epic

```
"customfield_10002": "PROJ-3875",
```

I figured this would be the spot to add some JSON but I feel like there's something non-obvious I'm missing.
[image]

I've tried adding just the above in a bunch of different ways but Google searching has left me slightly puzzled.

It's worth noting that without this section filled in, it does create a stand-alone ticket just fine.

Comment: Did you wrap the custom field in fields object? https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/update-epic-link-via-rest-api-779158615.html

Answer (score 1):

We opened a ticket with DD and they realized that their documentation UI was not accurate. To successfully put it under an epic you simply need to just type the ticket in a string:
`"PROJ-1234"`